# How can I efficiently compare the properties of two large lists of objects in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a dataset of two lists of objects, which has an ID that will be consistent in both lists but other properties that may or may not be different. How can I most efficiently retrieve the ones that are different based on one or more properties?

My usual approach has been something along the lines of this. My object is set up like:

```
   public class Person
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }

            public bool IsEqual(Person other)
            {
                if (Name != other.Name)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                if (Age != other.Age)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Where the IsEqual comparator is used to compare it to some equivalent object.

And then my method for finding modified people is like:

```
  public static List<Person> FindModifiedPeople(List<Person> listA, List<Person> listB)
        {
            var modifiedPeople = new List<Person>();
            foreach (var personA in listA)
            {
                var matchingPerson = listB.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID == personA.ID);
                if (matchingPerson == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (!personA.IsEqual(matchingPerson))
                {
                    modifiedPeople.Add(personA);
                }
            }
            return modifiedPeople;
        }
```

In my dataset, I don't care about people that are in listB but not listA, so I don't need to loop through both lists. I only need to check listA for the element in listB (that may or may not be there) and return a list of people that have been modified (with the elements from listA).

This approach worked fine for reasonably small lists, but now I have two lists with about 160,000 people and this approach takes several minutes. Is there any way to make this method more efficient while still returning what I need it do?

Comment: Do you have to use lists? If you have the ID of the person could you not store them in something like a Dictionary?

Comment: Do you really need to compare lists together? Why not just track within the object if it has been updated and expose that as a boolean property (i.e. ``person.IsDirty`)?

Comment: Though I now realise that `person.IsDirty` may not be the best naming convention...

Comment: Also, dont reinvent the wheel here, override [Equals(object obj)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of writing your own `IsEqual()`

Comment: Note that your "usual" approach to handling sets of objects is very unusual... Lists are really bad at pretty much any set operations - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113173/set-operation-in-net-c-sharp for guidance...

Comment: What does "efficient" mean to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can change your lists to be a `Dictionary<int, Person>` with the person's ID as the key they this would work for you. This will run in `O(n)` as opposed to your `O(n^2)`.

```
public static List<Person> FindModifiedPeople(Dictionary<int, Person> dictA, Dictionary<int, Person> dictB)
{
    var modifiedPeople = new List<Person>();
    foreach (var personA in dictA)
    {
        Person matchingPerson;
        if(dictB.TryGetValue(personA.Key, out matchingPerson))
        {
            if (!personA.Value.IsEqual(matchingPerson))
            {
                modifiedPeople.Add(personA.Value);
            }
        }
    }
    return modifiedPeople;
}
```

You could also change the return type from List to another Dictionary as well depending on what you need it for.

EDIT

As @maccettura pointed out in his comment, you really should override the built in equals method. That would make your code look something like this.

```
public override bool Equals(Object obj)
{
    if (obj == null || GetType() != obj.GetType())
        return false;

    var otherPerson = (Person)obj;

    if (Name != otherPerson.Name)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (Age != otherPerson.Age)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This will allow your code to work with any stuff that is expecting to use the default Equals method as opposed to your custom one.

Comment: I think it might be good to mention overriding `Equals()` too (might as well give OP some better practices)

Comment: Yeah. I didn't say anything just cause you already put it in your comment, but I will add it here.

Comment: Wow! That made a huge difference! That's amazing, thank you. 

Also, yeah I do know that I should be overriding Equals(). My colleague has already added an override for Equals, because he wants to return true when *only* comparing IDs and doesn't care about the properties. So his override is something like:

public override bool Equals(Person other) {
   if (ID != other.ID) {
    return false;
}
   return true;
}

And obviously in my case, I want Equals to specifically compare the properties. I wasn't really sure how to settle this dilemma, so I made my one a separate method.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that the comparison is the bottleneck? I think that the problem comes form the search you do in this line:

```
var matchingPerson = listB.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID == personA.ID);
```

There, you are doing a search with a logartihmic complexity of O(n), which coupled with the `foreach` loop gives a total complexity of O(n^2). Instead, you could create a dictionary upfront, which takes some time, but in which lookups are much faster. The dictionary should have the ID as keys, and can be easily created like this BEFORE THE `foreach` LOOP:

```
var dictB = listB.ToDictionary(p => p.ID);
```

After that, your lookup would be much faster, like this:

```
    Person matchingPerson;
    if (dictB.TryGetValue(personA.ID, out matchingPerson))
    {
        if (!personA.IsEqual(matchingPerson))
        {
            modifiedPeople.Add(personA);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, the FirstOrDefault was indeed the bottleneck rather than the comparator. I've changed it to make a Dictionary out of the List (I do need the List for other purposes), and even including that overhead the lookup is significantly faster. I'd mark both you and Michael Sharp as accepted answers if I could!